# How to use custom fonts in a Mac OS quicklook extension?

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, quicklook

I need to use a custom font in a QuickLook extension.

In the main application where the extension is embedded, I already use this font without problems.
So I tried to use the key `ATSApplicationFontsPath` in the `Info.plist` as well, but that doesn't seem to be enough.
The target membership of the font file is checked for both the app and the extension target.

But `NSFont(name: "MyCustomFont", size: 14.0)` returns `nil` and `NSFontManager.shared.availableFonts` does not contain the font. (It does in the main app though)

Is this even possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like I had the entry in the `info.plist` in the wrong place. ‍♂️
It was not at root level.

After I corrected that, the font was loaded and used.